# How to set text to div input/textarea in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set/add a text content to a div element that is a React.js generated component and doesn't have `value` attribute on it.

For example, I'm working on set a text content on a tweet on Twitter, the HTML part is like e.g.:

```html
<div aria-label="Tweet text" aria-multiline="true" data-testid="tweetTextarea_0" role="textbox">
  <span data-text="true">Hello everyone, this is my first tweet.</span>
</div>
```

A JavaScript code like `document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Tweet text"]').value = "Hello everyone, this is my second tweet."` doesn't work as I could expect.

So what can we do to set a text/value to a React.js (or Vue.js or such) input div?

Comment: Usually `useState` hook is used for updating a state in react .

Comment: use `innerHTML` or `innerText` instead of value

Comment: @nullptr I don't think that is how React components works.

Comment: if you're using value, you can use both of those as well. ideally you shouldn't be using any of those three in react.

Comment: @AnoopD Is it accessible from the client side? Well anyways I'd try using the React dev tools then.

Comment: @丶Limeー来夢丶  Think you have to use `localStorage` along with `useState` .